# How to select your class (for http response) in swagger

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, swagger, openapi

*Note I am using kotlin language but this is true for java as well.*

**Application info: kotlin\java , spring-boot, rest-api , openDoc-3**

I have my own wrapper class for the response. But because of this, swagger does not understand what I want to return

I have my own wrapper class for the response. But because of this, swagger does not understand what I want to return

```
data class ResponseWrapper<T> (
    val data: T,
    val status: HttpStatus
): ResponseEntity<ResultSet<T>> (
    ResultSet(status = status, data = data), status
)

data class ResultSet<T> (
    val status: HttpStatus,
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    val timestamp: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    val data: T?
) {
    init {
        if (data == null || (data is List<*> && data.isEmpty()))
            throw ResourceNotFoundException("No content found!")
    }
}
```

This wrapper allows me to send any data in the data object

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "timestamp": "03-09-2023 11:30:11",
    "data":  {}
}
```

I specify in ApiResponse which class (ResponseWrapper) I return but it doesn't work.

```
@GetMapping
    @Operation(
        summary = "Get orders for expeditor",
        description = """
            Gets abbreviated information about orders as a list
            Note: Information is abbreviated. Some fields may be missing
        """,
    )
    @ApiResponses(
        value = [
            ApiResponse(
                responseCode = "200",
                content = [
                    Content(
                        mediaType = "application/json",
                        schema = Schema(
                            implementation = ResponseWrapper::class,

                        )

                    )
                ]

            ),
        ]
    )
    fun getForExpeditor(
        @AuthenticationPrincipal user: UserEntity,
        @RequestParam expeditorFilterParam: ExpeditorFilterParam
    ): ResponseWrapper<*> {
        return ResponseWrapper(
            orderExpeditorService.getAllOrdersForExpeditor(user, expeditorFilterParam),
            HttpStatus.OK
        )
    }
```

swagger displays this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uOLW.png)

`orderExpeditorService.getAllOrdersForExpeditor(user, expeditorFilterParam),` returns a List which is serialized to json

I want swagger to display a wrapper with the date I need

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "timestamp": "03-09-2023 11:30:11",
    "data":  
         {
           orderDTO-Json
         }
}
```

how to do it?